# Is using fieldset and labels in XHTML discouraged?

Tags: xhtml, label, fieldset

I heard there was fundamental lack of web-browser comprehension of those, and often IE6,7, opera would flounder trying to display them.

Is that indeed true? Should those be avoided? And while we're at it, do they have a specific advantage when using forms? (except for the impeccably square frame around)

Comment: I don't think I could imagine a world where an `input` of `type="checkbox"` didn't have a `label` attached to it :-)

Comment: I'm gonna take that as a joke. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds unreasonable. In fact, XHTML 1.x STRICT requires a block-level element like `fieldset` to enclose `input` elements. As for labels, they are valuable for users with screen readers. I would not substitute either tag.

Comment: That seems logical. Only I've come accross different links that tell otherwise: "not all browsers or devices currently choose to honour these tags and attribute"
http://accessify.com/features/tutorials/forms/accessible-forms-pt2.php

Comment: I think you misunderstand; the article doesn't say that it will do any harm (unless you do something silly like move the label really far away from the input element it's associated with), but merely that not all screen readers are smart enough to take advantage of it.